# R - Only first condition in WHILE loop is being satisfied

Tags: r, while-loop

I've simplified the following code from my actual project, since the issue is the same:

For some reason, when I run the following code:

```
x <- 1
y <- 5
z <- 20

while((x<y) && (z<28)){
  x <- x+1
  z <- z+1
}

paste(x, y, z)
```

My output is

```
"5, 5, 24"
```

Why would this WHILE loop stop running when variable z is still below 28?

Comment: you are replacing `x` and 'z' in each iteration instead of appending

Comment: @akrun - That's my intention. I want x and z to continue updating themselves until x is no longer less than y (i.e., no longer less than 5) AND until z is no longer less than 28. The loop, however, only stops running once the first condition is met.

Comment: It is because you are using `&&` instead of `&`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The while loop stops when x hits the y value if you want it to continue change it from "x is less than y AND z is less than 28" to "x is less than y OR z is less than 28."

Comment: Thanks, Brian! Can't believe that was such an easy fix. In my head, I was understanding WHILE to be more like UNTIL.